# Unable to generate Hibernate reverse engineering using Embedded Derby connection in NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, hibernate, derby

I'm using `embedded derby` with `Hibernate` but 
 when I try to generate **Reverse Engineering** after creating `Hibernate.cfg.xml` I'm getting following error.

> `Cannot establish database connection with selected Hibernate Configuration file. Please verify the database connection details in hibernate.cfg.xml.`

Because of :

> `Caused by: ERROR XSDB8: Warning: Derby (instance a816c00e-0171-a746-cd67-000019e679e8) is attempting to boot the database may still be active.  Only one instance of Derby should boot a database at a time.`

I'm connecting `Derby Embedded` in **NetBeans** **`Services>`** window for creating **`Hibernate.cfg.xml`** but when performing **`Hibernate Reverse Engineering`** wizard it does connect again but though it could connect successfully in
***services>*** window of `NetBeans IDE` getting  :

`Cannot establish database connection with selected Hibernate Configuration file. Please verify the database connection details in hibernate.cfg.xml.`

and also :

> log contains `ERROR XSDB8:`

Further even I can connect using **DBeaver** though I'm facing `ERROR XSDB8:` so what's wrong only with **Reverse Engineering Wizard?**

Here is `Hibernate.cfg.xml` :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:clientieFX;create=true</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">app</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">app</property>
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

May it could be achieve configuring in `Hibernate.cfg.xml`.

> I aslo disconnected the instance programitacally using

`DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");`

That disconnect the connection but further when I repeat `Hibernate Reverse Engineering` wizard it still giving same error.

**So why it cause error though there's no instance is booted anymore?**

I'm using **`NetBeans 11.0`**, **`BellSoft JDK 11.0.6+10-LTS`**, **`Hibernate 4.3.1.(now updated to 5.4.14)`** and **`Derby 10.15.2.0`**

Answer (score 1):

No, please don't just delete the lock file! It is there for a reason, it is protecting you from accidentally damaging your database!

You are correct, with the Embedded configuration of Derby, only one Java program at a time can have the database open.

The simplest solution is to shutdown the first connection before you make the next connection. Is that possible for you to do?

There are more complex solutions, such as running the Derby Network Server rather than running Derby in the Embedded configuration, but generally I think you should choose the simplest solution that will work for your use case.

For more complete information on the db.lck file: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/devguide/cdevdvlp20458.html

Comment: Hmmm. You could try completely restarting your computer. If you want to use Embedded Derby, you will have to be able to arrange that only one copy of the Derby Engine at a time is accessing the database. In order to share the database among multiple applications, you must use the Client-Server configuration of Derby. You can learn more about that here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/getstart/cgsquck70629.html

Comment: If you're not seeing your data, there could be a variety of reasons. You might have connected to the wrong database instance. You might have connected as the wrong user. You might not have committed the schema updates and so they got rolled back. There are other reasons. Most important thing to check is your ConnectionURL because it is how you determine whether two apps are connecting to the same database or not.